# NSWindowGraphicContext?

Tags: cocoa, macos, reverse-engineering, macos-carbon

I was wondering what is NSWindowGraphicContext and how can I access it? 
It seems hidden. Anyway when I following code className turns out to be NSWindowGraphicContext.

```
NSGraphicsContext *graphiccontext = [NSGraphicsContext currentContext];
const char* className             = class_getName([graphiccontext class]);
```

Same thing with CGContextRef.

Documentation says

> "A window graphics context is a graphics context that you can use to draw into a window. Note that because Quartz 2D is a graphics engine and not a window management system, you use one of the application frameworks to obtain a graphics context for a window."

But it does not give the name of the header or details for creating that like it does for bitmap context and  PDF graphics context? I would like to know more about them.

I assume Apple don't want to expose those details to user. But I need to know more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a private subclass used by Apple which you aren't supposed to know about. As such, there is no public documentation or headers. It will be created automatically for your windows. You can get it either by accessing the current context (as you do in your question), or like this:

```
[NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithWindow:theWindow];
```

If you want to know more about the class, you can run [class-dump](http://www.codethecode.com/projects/class-dump/) on AppKit to get a header. Using the information from the header, you might be able to create new contexts, but they will likely be hard to set up properly, and it is better to ask the system for one.

Comment: I used class-dump. I found lots of interesting classes related to graphics context. I would like to know more about quartz private api's. class-dump works only with objective c libraries and binaries.
Is there any way to dump quartz private headers?

Comment: @Rahul No. You could use `nm` to list all of the symbols in a file, which includes functions and constants, but the only reason class-dump works so well is that all of that information has to be stored for a dynamic language such as objective-c to work.

Comment: I tried otx tool get a dump. Its not exactly a dump but had names of all the private quartz functions in assemble code. But we don't get complete signature from otx tool. I have not used nm yet. I will try that tonight and will post an update.

Comment: I tried nm tool to. But it to gives a function name only and no proper hint on signature.